# Listing JAR within WAR

Tags: jar, war, shell

```
jar -tvf hello.war
```

However, my `.war` also contains some `.jar` in a `lib` folder within the `.war`.

I need a command display the contents of all the `.jar`s within the `.war`.

The reason I need command line and not use tools like Winrar is because I need to incorporate it in my UNIX shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a short script.

```
TEMPDIR=`mktemp -d`
REALPATH=`pwd`/$1
(cd $TEMPDIR && jar xf $REALPATH)
for j in `find $TEMPDIR -name "*.jar"`; do echo `basename $j`; jar tvf $j; done
rm -rf $TEMPDIR
```

E.G.

```
$ ./go.sh x.war
z.jar
     0 Sat Jul 30 21:53:20 EST 2011 META-INF/
    71 Sat Jul 30 21:53:20 EST 2011 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   182 Sat Jul 30 21:52:54 EST 2011 go.sh
    25 Sat Jul 30 21:50:46 EST 2011 zz.sh
x.jar
     0 Sat Jul 30 21:33:28 EST 2011 META-INF/
    71 Sat Jul 30 21:33:28 EST 2011 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Sat Jul 30 21:33:20 EST 2011 x
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for sharing. What about an ear which has multiple war and jars and those wars inturn have jar like below.                ear(jars,wars(jars))  Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Not  really useful in a shell script, but the easiest way I've found to do this when looking at webapps interactively is to open them in emacs; archive mode understands jars, and just needs to be told about .wars, by adding
`(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.war\\'" . archive-mode))` to your `.emacs`.  Then you can open the war like a normal directory, plus anything insde it:

[image: Screenshot of archive mode with open .war]